# Fortran code to open some program and then move on

Tags: cmd, fortran

```
program test
call system("notepad")
..........  !next task
end program
```

This program opens the notepad and then does not move on to the 'next task' until i manually close the notepad. But I want the whole program to execute completely with notepad still opened.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Which Fortran are you using? Fortran 2008 introduced `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`.

Comment: @S.Ahn I have tried this command with wait=.false. option, but it still works the same way.

Comment: It may depend on the operating system and other things, it doesn't have to actually run asynchronously. I recommend to use threads, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows (which you are likely using, since notepad is a common program on it) replace the appropriate line with

```
call system("start notepad")
```

This works with g95 and gfortran on Windows 8.1. Microsoft says that start "starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command".

Comment: this is a nice solution for my particular example.

Comment: Good possibility. Obviously I know better Linux, that's why I was writing about pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to do it. As @S.Ahn comments [`EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html) has asynchronous execution (use the `WAIT` argument). However, whether it will actually run asynchronously is processor dependent.

Another way is to use some threading. You could use [tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/6nj43o69j/index.html) in OpenMP, which are in the standard version 3.0.

I use [POSIX threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) for a similar purpose. You then just do `call system()` or equivalent inside the thread. There are Fortran wrappers for this library, for example, https://github.com/ohm314/forthreads